# Are there unsolved indeterminate limits?

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

I find the question itself is hard to put precisely. I apologize in advance. A simple version could be:

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of functions obtained via elementary binary operations (sum, product, power, end their inverses) and composition, including polynomials and sinusoidals ($cos(x)$ and $sin(x)$). For example $f(x)=e^{e^x}+cos(x)$. Basically the functions one encounters in basic calculus. The question is the following:

Are there $f,g\in \mathcal{F}$ such that:
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=\infty,$$ 
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)=\infty,$$ 
but such that the limit $$\lim_{x\to \infty}\dfrac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ is unsolved? What I mean by this is that no one in the mathematical community knows if the limit exists, or even if existence is guarranteed, no one knows if the limit is finite on infinit.

Comment: Do you mean that the limit is unsolved, or that the limit does not exist?

Comment: FWIW there are two ways to modify this question to avoid a correct-but-trivial answer: ask for an explicit example of such an $f$ and $g$, or ask the general question of whether there is an algorithm for determining the answer given a choice of $f$ and $g$ (so shifting from "people know" to "people have an algorithm to find out").

Comment: @NoahSchweber, thank you. The question obviously needs editing. But I'm not sure what having an algorithm would mean.

Comment: @TheJu Perhaps surprisingly, we have [a precise language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computability_theory) for talking about algorithms; the question of whether we can computably determine whether the limit of the ratio of two such functions exists (and/or calculate that limit if so) is a precise one.

Comment: @TheJu For example, [Richardson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem) is a result of this general flavor (although not addressing this specific problem).

Answer (score 10):

Given access to these elementary functions, it's fairly easy to convert statements about, say, rational approximations to $ \pi $ into the existence of a particular limit.

For example, it's unknown if the irrationality measure of $ \pi $ is equal to $ 2 $ or not (in the sense of measure theory, almost all irrational numbers have irrationality measure $ 2 $). It's easy to see that this statement is equivalent to saying that for any $ \epsilon > 0 $,  $ \sin(n) $ is never within $ O(1/n^{2 + \epsilon}) $ of $ 0 $ for all but finitely many values of $ n $, which in turn is equivalent to saying that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp(-n^{2 + \epsilon} |\sin(n)|) $$

is equal to $ 0 $ for all $ \epsilon > 0 $, so for instance if you pick $ \epsilon = 1 $ it's unknown if this limit exists or not. If it exists, it's easy to see it must be equal to $ 0 $. If you don't like absolute values, you can instead formulate an equivalent statement as

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \exp(-n^{4 + \epsilon} \sin^2(n)) = 0 $$

This is not exactly in the form you want, but you should be able to put it into that form if you multiply and divide by some appropriate function diverging sufficiently quickly to infinity, say $ \exp(\exp(n)) $. This just obscures the basic idea of the construction, however.

Comment: Great answer! I stated the question with $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ just for simplicity.

Comment: There is a caveat here: $n$ should range only over integers. Otherwise, the limit proveably does _not_ exist (what happens when $n$ is a multiple of $\pi$, versus other points?). One might wonder if this question intends to ask for a limit of a function of a _real_ variable.

Comment: @The_Sympathizer It doesn't change anything because it's possible to use elementary functions to construct sufficiently good approximations to the indicator function of $ \mathbb Z $ as $ t \to \infty $ (consider, for example, $ t \to \exp(-e^t \sin^2(\pi t)) $). I leave it as an exercise to figure out how you adapt that along with my answer to construct a limit of a real variable which is also not known to exist.

Answer (score -2):

There are a finite number of mathematicians.  Each mathematician has thought of only a finite number of functions in $\mathcal F$.
 But there are infinitely many many members of $\mathcal F$.
So there are infinitely many $f/g$ that no mathematician has ever
even thought of, therefore doesn't know the limiting behaviour of.

Comment: This is technically an answer, but I think it really demonstrates that the question hasn't been asked perfectly - see my comment below the OP. I think it would be more appropriate as a comment.

Comment: An interesting question is "is there an analytical solution to every limit problem ?", in a sense that compares to Liouville's theorem about integrability.

Comment: I agree with @NoahSchweber, but I do love your answer, Robert. You could make an argument to the effect of "Let $\mathcal{F}$_t$ be the set of all such functions, and their limits, which have been computed until $t=$this moment. Make an argument about some combination of these functions and their limits which is not in that set, etc.

Comment: My original doubt goes more in that line @YvesDaost. But, how do you define "analytical solution"? That's the part I struggled the most stating the question. The idea of "having an algorithm" didn't convince me either Noah. For example, without L'Hopital lemma, we wouldn't have solving algorithms, in many cases. What would be the set of "usable tricks" for an algorithm?