# Limit of $\lim_{x \to \infty}\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}$ using nothing but L'Hopitals rule

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find a general procedure for solving any limit. I went about it by transforming any indeterminate form into $\infty / \infty$ or $0/0$ and applying L'Hopitals rule and repeating this process until a determinate form is reached.

This particular problem seems to not give me a solution using this procedure. Since the indeterminate form is $\infty - \infty$, it is transformed into $$\ln \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}}}{e^{\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}}}$$ which is of the form $\infty / \infty$. But applying L'Hopitals rule doesn't seem to lead anywhere after taking the derivatives. Is this method not sufficient for these kinds of limits, or am I missing something?

Comment: unfortunately there isn't any general algorithm (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3671705)) however for the limit you're asking you can just write as e^{...} and the thing in the top approaches 0 either by differentiation or by bernoulli's inequality

Comment: Perhaps using $ a^{3}-b^{3}=\left(a-b\right)\left(a^{2}+ab+b^{2}\right) $ 
and also $ a=\sqrt[3]{\left(x+1\right)^{2}},b=\sqrt[3]{\left(x-1\right)^{2}} $
Will lead us to:$$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{\left(x+1\right)^{2}}-\sqrt[3]{\left(x-1\right)^{2}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(x+1\right)^{2}-\left(x-1\right)^{2}}{\left(\sqrt[3]{\left(x+1\right)^{2}}\right)^{2}+\sqrt[3]{\left(x+1\right)^{2}\left(x-1\right)^{2}}+\left(\sqrt[3]{\left(x-1\right)^{2}}\right)^{2}} $$

Answer (score 2):

This is standard $\infty-\infty$. To find $\lim f-g$ transform it to
$\lim \frac{f}{\frac{1}{1-g/f}}$. Then L'Hopital it.

Comment: This answer is better than mine (+1) as the OP wanted to use L'Hopital's rule.  For this question the most useful form is: $$f-g=\frac{1-g/f}{f^{-1}}.$$

Comment: How can I know which form to transform to in general, if I always want to use L'Hopital's? I used a transformation from [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#List_of_indeterminate_forms) for this particular case of $\infty - \infty$, which ended up not working. Is there a transformation that always works?

Comment: @AyyLmao: You need to turn $\infty-\infty$ into $0/0$ or $\infty/\infty$. Similarly  for $0^\infty$ or $\infty^0$ (use $\log$). For example $\lim_{n\to \infty} (3n^2+5n+3)^{1/n}$.

Comment: I will try to clarify my question. I understand that it needs to be turned into $0/0$ or $\infty / \infty$ for it to be possible to use L'Hopital's. What I don't understand is why some transformations, for example the transformation that I used $ \lim f - g = \ln \lim \frac{e^f}{e^g} $, are intractable for L'Hopital's, while some like yours aren't. Does there exist a transformation from $\infty - \infty$ to $0/0$ or $\infty / \infty$ that always "behaves nicely" with L'Hopital's?

Comment: The derivative of $e^f$ is $e^f f'$. Since the lim  of $f'/g'$ is 1 the L'Hopital of your transformation is the original limit so your transformation cannot work and is never used.

Answer (score 1):

We have:
\begin{eqnarray*}\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}&=&x^{\frac23}\left(\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{\frac23}-\left(1-\frac1x\right)^{\frac23}\right)\\
&=&2x^{-\frac13}\frac{\left(\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{\frac23}-\left(1-\frac1x\right)^{\frac23}\right)}{\left(\left(1+\frac1x\right)-\left(1-\frac1x\right)\right)}
\end{eqnarray*}

As $x\to \infty$ we have $$\frac{\left(\left(1+\frac1x\right)^{\frac23}-\left(1-\frac1x\right)^{\frac23}\right)}{\left(\left(1+\frac1x\right)-\left(1-\frac1x\right)\right)}\to \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right\vert_{t=1}t^{\frac23}=\frac23.$$

As $\frac43x^{-\frac13}\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$, we conclude $$\sqrt[3]{(x+1)^2}-\sqrt[3]{(x-1)^2}\to 0$$ as $x\to\infty$.